# SSIS Package Error: failed to lock variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, database-administration

I am using SQL server 2016 and SSIS. I have a package in which i added a Rebuild Index Task.[image]
 When i run the package it works fine, but when i run the package in a scheduled job i got following error message.

> Rebuild Index: Error: Failed to lock variable "RunID" for read access
>   with error 0xc0010001 "The variable cannot be found. This occurs when
>   an attempt is made to retrieve a variable from the variable collection
>   on a container during execution of the package and the variable is not
>   there. The Variable name may have changed or the variable is not being
>   created."". No Idea why i am getting this error. [image]

Comment: Is RunID a variable you are using and have created?

Comment: No, I didn't added any variables. I just added Rebuild Index Task and Reorganize task in control flow with respective connections and database.